# how would you write R.compose using R.o?

Tags: ramda.js

Seems like some use to knowing a good pattern to make an n-step composition or pipeline from a binary function. Maybe it's obvious or common knowledge.

What I was trying to do was `R.either(predicate1, predicate2, predicate3, ...)` but `R.either` is one of these binary functions. I thought `R.composeWith` might be part of a good solution but didn't get it to work right. Then I think `R.o` is at the heart of it, or perhaps `R.chain` somehow.

Maybe there's a totally different way to make an n-ary `either` that could be better than a `"compose-with"(R.either)`... interested if so but trying to ask a more general question than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way for converting a binary function into one that takes many arguments is by using `R.reduce`. This requires at least the arguments of the binary function and its return type to be the same type.

For your example with `R.either`, it would look like:

```
const eithers = R.reduce(R.either, R.F)
const fooOr42 = eithers([ R.equals("foo"), R.equals(42) ])
```

This accepts a list of predicate functions that will each be given as arguments to `R.either`.

The `fooOr42` example above is equivalent to:

```
const fooOr42 = R.either(R.either(R.F, R.equals("foo")), R.equals(42))
```

You can also make use of [`R.unapply`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#unapply) if you want to convert the function from accepting a list of arguments, to a variable number of arguments.

```
const eithers = R.unapply(R.reduce(R.either, R.F))
const fooOr42 = eithers(R.equals("foo"), R.equals(42))
```

The approach above can be used for any type that can be combined to produce a value of the same type, where the type has some "monoid" instance. This just means that we have a binary function that combines the two types together and some "empty" value, which satisfy some simple laws:

- Associativity: `combine(a, combine(b, c)) == combine(combine(a, b), c)`
- Left identity: `combine(empty, a) == a`
- Right identity: `combine(a, empty) == a`

Some examples of common types with a monoid instance include:

- arrays, where the empty list is the empty value and `concat` is the binary function.
- numbers, where `1` is the empty value and `multiply` is the binary function
- numbers, where `0` is the empty value and `add` is the binary function

In the case of your example, we have predicates (a function returning a `boolean` value), where the empty value is `R.F` (a.k.a `(_) => false`) and the binary function is `R.either`. You can also combine predicates using `R.both` with an empty value of `R.T` (a.k.a `(_) => true`), which will ensure the resulting predicate satisfies all of the combined predicates.

It is probably also worth mentioning that you could alternatively just use [`R.anyPass`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#anyPass) :)